# Como enviar parametros por metodo get a api

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio, .net

Intento enviarlo de esta manera hacia la api

```
if (dato.Equals( "depa"))
{
  model.nompais = combo2.ToString();

          
            url = $"http://localhost:44366/api/listar" + dato+"/{"+combo2+"}";
             

        }
        else if(dato.Equals("ciudad"))
        {
           
            url = $"http://localhost:44366/api/listar" + dato + "/{" + combo2 + "}";

            ]
        }
        else if (dato.Equals("pais")) { 

        string respuesta = await GetHttp(url);
        List<model> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<model>>(respuesta);
        combo.DataSource = lst;
        combo.DisplayMember = "nombre";
        combo.ValueMember = "id";
        }
```

la intención es que cuando escoja en el combo box el pais, se despliegue los departamenos de ese pais  y asi mismo con la ciudad. Estoy usando store procedure con sql server

**api**

```
    public static List<model> Listar_ciudad(model c)
     {
          List<model> oListaciudad = new List<model>();
            using (SqlConnection oConexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.rutaConexion))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_listar_ciudad", oConexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depa", c.nomdepa);

                try
                {
                    oConexion.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            oListaciudad.Add(new model()
                            {
                                id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]),
                                nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString(),
                                iddepa = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_depa"]),
                                idpais = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_pais"])
                            });
                            ;
                        }
                    }
                    return oListaciudad;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return oListaciudad;
                }
            }
        }
```

la api de listar_departamento es exactamente igual solo que donde ene sta dice ciudad en la otra dice departamento porque si la envio sin parametros me mostraria un monton de departamenos y ciudades de todo el mundo

**error**

```
La solicitud contiene un cuerpo de entidad, pero no un encabezado Content-Type. El tipo de medio inferido 'application/octet-stream' no se admite para este recurso
```

Comment: y cual es el problema? llega al controller del api tu peticion o no?

Comment: Solo pasale por QueryParameters en la URL y a la hora de enviar en tu HttpClient indicarle que tu Metodo es por GET,
Ejemplo: apiUrl.com/get?parameterOne=AnyValue&parameterTwo=AnyValue

Comment: La solicitud contiene un cuerpo de entidad, pero no un encabezado Content-Type. El tipo de medio inferido 'application/octet-stream' no se admite para este recurso ese es el error que me aparece y no he podido solucionar

Comment: y el codigo del controller tenes para agregar?